# Discord.js Ping "NaN"

Tags: discord.js

I am attempting to make a ping command for my bot

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Shows the bot\'s ping',
    execute(message) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        embed.setTitle(' Pong!');
        embed.setDescription(`**Ping:** ${client.ws.ping}`);
        message.channel.send(embed);
    },
};
```

The bot starts when I load it, but when I enter (prefix)ping into the text channel, it puts

```
 Pong!
Ping: NaN
```

What should I do to show the ping?

Comment: Please show your command handler.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass client from your base code (where you do `client.login()` and `client.on('message',...)`.

If you had something like this

```
client.commands.get('ping').execute(message);
```

add client in the parameter being pass as well.

```
client.commands.get('ping')execute(message,client);
```

and within the module, no longer declare a new client but rather, include it in the parameter from execute,

```
execute(message, client) {...}
```